# which layout displays multiple image buttons?

Tags: android, image, button, layout

Hi I'm trying to add an activity that displays 4 images (imagine a square cut to quarters) where each image shows a different one when clicked, I have tried a few layouts using image buttons to no avail but then read here my answer is a grid view using image pager but when implementing this I get small images spaced quite far apart in grid view is there a better way please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's always 2x2 images you can simply use a vertical linear layout and two horizontal layouts in it and then put your images as ImageButton or ImageView inside the horizontal layouts...

if it needs to be dynamic a gridlayout would probably be a good idea...

however, you need to provide more detailed information on what the issue is, if you need a more detailed answer...

(edit: I meant gridview, gridlayout is only available since api level 14)

Comment: Wish I could mark yours as right too as it also provides exactly what I wanted, sorry for being a little vague, think it needed to be as I wanted something simple (and I'm a rank amateur) which again your answer accomplishes

Comment: this is what I ended up doing and will ammend this to be the correct sneer, but I wondered now that I have done this my images are scaling really badly is there an easier way to scale than bitmap factories, guessing this is the way to do it but have not been able to get my head around it

Comment: You can use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, boolean))
I'm not sure about efficiency or quality though. If by scaling badly you mean positioning of the scaled bmp you should also look at the ScaleType of your imageviews (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html )

In general it's a good idea to look at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html when working with large images...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout in order to add your ImageButtons and have all the control to your hands for location of buttons, size etc.

A different point of view, is to break your screen into 4 Rectangles (Rects). 
Something like this :

```
Rect upLeftRect = new Rect(0,0,screenWidth/2 , screenHeight/2);
Rect upRightRect = new Rect(screenWidth/2,0,screenWidth,screenHeight/2);
Rect downLeftRect = new Rect(0,screenHeight/2, screenWidth/2 , screenHeight);
Rect downRightRect = new Rect(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2, screenWidth,screenHeight);
```

The, attach an onTouchListener on your relativeLayout, something like this in your constructor:

```
yourRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

And finally , inside the onTouch method you will have something like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
  if(upLeftRect.contains( ( int ) e.getX(), (int) e.getY){
    // do whatever you want, i guess that you want some alpha animation or something like this
  }else if(upRightRect.contains( (int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY(){
    // bla bla.. :)
  } // do the rest conditions your self!!
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Omg that is exactly what I was after @karvoynistas you are a legend!